# Atom package for auto refresh the browser

Tags: browser, editor, atom-editor

Can anyone please suggest which package I can use in Atom which will enable the auto browser refresh when I save my code. If Atom doesn't support the browser functionality directly then is there any other option?
Currently I am using the Vagrant environment so my code runs on a remote server simulator. 
Does anyone have any suggestions regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl-shift-h` refreshes the built in browser but not automatically after you save. But you can use the shortcut yourself after saving file.

Comment: Currently, i have implemented the BrowserSyn and it works fine. However, if we have the **Preview HTML** for atom then also your saving will reflect in the side pane. Thanks